How should I exchange data between python and OriginLab when using library originpro?
I wanna use both origin and python for data proceeding in the same time, and I don't know how. I've found some examples on originhelp, but I have some problems with them. Someone, please provide a code example what will write a column with random values created in python
I don't understand why in my case code provided on originhelp doesn't work

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Here is the sample of code. You have to use code builder inside the originpro and have an active worksheet. To run this code, u have to install the package astropy (Tools->PythonPackages).
import originpro as op
import numpy as np
from astropy.coordinates import SkyCoord
from astropy import units as u

c = SkyCoord(1.2*u.rad, 0.5*u.rad, frame='icrs')

wks = op.find_sheet() # col A contains three numbers: 10, 20, 30, col B contains 40, 50, 60

decls = wks.to_list(1) # col B

ra = wks.to_list(0) # col A


objects_prepare = [(ra[i]/57.3, decls[i]/57.3) for i in range(len(decls))] 


objects = [SkyCoord(decl*u.rad, ra*u.rad, frame='icrs')  for decl, ra in objects_prepare]


for value, i in enumerate(objects):
    objects_prepare[value] = (float(i.galactic.to_string().split(' ')[0]),float(i.galactic.to_string().split(' ')[1]))

lst1 = [value[0] for value in objects_prepare]
lst2 = [value[1] for value in objects_prepare]

wks.from_list(4, lst1) #
wks.from_list(5, lst2) # writing a proceeding result into column 4 and 5

Second code example:
import originpro as op


def corr_func(x_predicted, y_predicted, y, sigma_y): # this func gets predicted x, y and measured x, y and returns some number. in this example we don't use sigma_y
    return abs(y-y_predicted)
    
def linear_func(a, b, x): # this func return y for a, b and x
    return a*x+b
    
wks = op.find_sheet() # col A contains three numbers: 10, 20, 30, col B contains 40, 50, 60

z = wks.to_list(0) # col A

T = wks.to_list(1) # col B

sigmas = wks.to_list(2) # col C

# now we will try to draw the best straight line through the points y = ax+b. T will be our y, z will be our x. We will check a in range 2-4 and b in range 2-4 with step 0.1

a_range = [2+0.1*i for i in range(21)]

b_range = [2+0.1*i for i in range(21)]

# now we are going to calculate a deviation and find the best pair of a, b:

best_choice = 1e10 # here we determine a start deviation with a large number
best_a = 0
best_b = 0


points_list = [(z[i], T[i]) for i in range(len(z))] # list of points, every element is a tuple (z, T)

for i in range(21):
    for j in range(21):
        current_choice = sum([corr_func(value_z, value_T, linear_func(a_range[i], b_range[j], value_z), 0) for value_z, value_T in points_list]) #here we calculate an exact value of deviation as a sum of points deviation
        if current_choice < best_choice:
            best_choice = current_choice
            best_a = a_range[i]
            best_b = b_range[j]
        
best_pair = [best_a, best_b]
            
wks.from_list(3, best_pair)

